# Iterate over global data subfolder in Eleventy / 11ty

Tags: json, static-site, nunjucks, eleventy

I'm using Eleventy and have created the subfolder `yummy` in my global data folder, that contains the following files:

```
\src\_data\yummy\drinks.json
\src\_data\yummy\food.json
```

When I use `{{ yummy | dump }}` I get the following output:

```
{
  "drinks":[
    {"name":"Milk","price":5},
    {"name":"Water","price":1}
  ],
  "food":[
    {"name":"Pizza","price":4},
    {"name":"Hot dog","price":2},
    {"name":"Sallad","price":1},
    {"name":"Avocado","price":3}
  ]
}
```

I want to create a list with all entries in both json-files. I almost have achieved this with the following loop:

```
<ul>
{% for key, val in yummy %}
<li>{{ val[0].name }} cost {{ val[0].price }}$</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

However, since I'm using [0], the output is only the first entry in each json-file:

```
- Milk cost 5$
- Pizza cost 4$
```

I want all entries and have tried the following, but get no output at all:

```
<ul>
{% for key, val in yummy %}
<li>{{ val[key].name }} cost {{ val[key].price }}$</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to solve this myself by adding a second loop.

```
<ul>
  {% for key, val in yummy %}
    {% for entry in val %}
    <li>{{ entry.name }} cost {{ entry.price }}$</li>
    {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Outputs as:

```
- Milk cost 5$
- Water cost 1$
- Pizza cost 4$
- Hot dog cost 2$
- Sallad cost 1$
- Avocado cost 3$
```